# Swift: change font and styling of a NSbutton

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, nsbutton

how do I change via code in swift for mac osx , the NSbutton title font type and font size after editing the font color? Via the Xcode gui editor is not possible to update the font when I change the title color.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

button.title = "Test"

button.font = NSFont(name: "Century Gothic Bold", size: 26)

This will change the title, font type and size of the NSButton.

Comment: That's in IOS, I m looking for it in OSX

Comment: I'm sorry bud but you are mistaken. I just created a new OS X project, added a button to the storyboard, linked the button into my ViewController, and put this into my viewDidLoad and it works just fine. Notice the 'NS' in the NSButton and NSFont. 'NS' is generally for OS X while 'UI' is generally for iOS.